# ERROR Could not load "versions.yml" from config bucket

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

- Get current deployment
  Success
- Get Spinnaker version
  Success
- Get released versions
  Failure
  Problems in Global:
  ! ERROR Could not load "versions.yml" from config bucket:
  Connection reset.
- Failed to load available Spinnaker versions.

Hi,

I was trying to use halyard behind proxy and it's failing to get versions.yml from google somewhere

Is there anyway I can pass the proxy information to halyard or how can I download the file and pass it to halyard ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem recently, my solution is below:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- halyard version: 0.41

In the file under /opt/halyard/bin/halyard, add the necessary proxy configuration to the variable DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS as described here. For example,

`DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=1080`

See [more details here](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/proxy_setup).